# Specflow - How to Make Pending test to not fail the whole test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, specflow, specrun

Hi I'm using specflow for automating my Web test . From last few days i m getting Pending tests make the whole test in a fail mode rather then Making it pass. Previously it was passing the test suite if one or 2 pending tests found  but from last week i m encountering issue like it is not passing the tests.

Can some one pls tell me how to make tests to be pass if Pending ?

Comment: what changed in the last few days? New specflow version? new CI system version?

Answer (score 2):

You can set Ignore for 'missingOrPendingStepsOutcome' attribute and try.

```
<specflow> 
....
....
<runtime 
      stopAtFirstError="false"
      missingOrPendingStepsOutcome="Ignore" />
....    
</specflow>
```

Courtesy: [Configuration in SpecFlow](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Configuration/)

Comment: well I tried that but that is making test Ignored not Pending . Is there any way to make it Pending ? As it used to work before

Comment: If i do upate as above it will show test is ignored but when i run the test from jenkins it is showing Red build ( with 5 pass and 2 Ignored tests). So how to deal with Jenkins and make it run ? 

I m using cmd to execute the test . Is there any thing i need to change for error level there?

Comment: I'm also getting a failure. With`"missingOrPendingStepsOutcome": "Ignore"`  pending tests are ignored, but with `"missingOrPendingStepsOutcome": "Pending"` they are showed as failed rather than as pending.